# Maven project JARs weirdly structured

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using Maven m2e as my Eclipse project.

My Maven project was acting weird so I right clicked my `pom.xml` and went to *run as -> maven build* then under goals I first did `eclipse:clean` and then `eclipse:eclipse`. Before I did that all my JARs were inside the Maven Dependencies folder. Now most of my jars are located in my project folder, outside the maven dependencies folder. Why is that? And how can I revert those changes?

This is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: There should be be an option under "maven" to "enable dependency management". Right click on the project to get to that. I'm guessing Eclipse has just decided to show these to you. The path it shows seems to point to them still being in your M2_repo

Comment: Also you seem to confuse the discontinued [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) and the m2e coming with eclipse. Both are valid choices but you should not mix them. `mvn eclipse:eclipse` even inserts the following comment into your .project file: NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.

Comment: You should not use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` anymore..Use M2E instead..

Comment: I see so when I try to do a maven build how can it be done? I right clicked my pom.xml and went to `run as -> maven build` but it asks to set a goal? All I want to do is mvn compile -> mvn build to build my project. Not sure what this goal is?

Comment: A typical would be `clean install`. For those are also shortcuts in the maven menu.

Comment: @DrHopfen so my goal should be `clean install`? Where can I get a list of all the preconfigured goal commands? I can't find any online.

Comment: Just install M2E and do "right click > Maven > Update Project..."

Comment: Find more information about the [maven build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). `clean install` essentially deletes your target folder and builds the artifact (going through the steps defined in the link) and installs it to the local maven repository.

Comment: @DrHopfen I see, so don't use any of the eclipse maven plugin commands like `eclipse:eclipse` anymore as a goal? Instead I can use actual maven commands like for an example, `mvn compile` in my goal? So if I want to do a maven compile I will set my goal as `compile`?

Comment: basically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` is a relic from ancient times, don't use it.

Basically, what it does is taking the information from a pom.xml and using it to create a native Eclipse project. That was a nice approach 5 years ago, when Eclipse didn't understand Maven projects, but ever since m2eclipse / m2e were introduced, this approach was deprecated in favor of these plugins that actually try to understand the pom.xml.